# How to customize .flow method of ImageDataGenerator (in Image processing) in keras

Tags: image, image-processing, keras

.flow function **reads in all the images at once** and then generates augmented data in batches. I have a memory concern and is it possible to manipulate the .flow function's source code in keras and then use it, **so that it could read in images in batches and then augment them and generate a batch of images for training and validation purposes.** I want to use it with train_on_batch function for training.

Comment: I removed the `processing` tag in favor of `image-processing`. The `processing` tag is for the programming language known as "Processing". Please read the description of a tag before deciding to use it.

Comment: Thanks John! my bad.

Comment: No problem -- part of the reason I make that comment is to let people know about Processing, which is a pretty cool language for making visual art. Without realizing it, you picked a pretty interesting tag.